# I completed the map quests and have 86 starites. Where are the rest?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

I've completed every quest in every area, and the world map is chock-full of check marks, but I only have 86 starite out of a possible 106. Where are the rest of the starites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape (Menu) -> Shards -> Object shards

These are pretty much hidden achievements such as the PBJ one:

> (wear maraccas and a banana suit at the same time to get a shard.)

Comment: Is there a way to get there faster? It looks like there's around 200 shards, and that will take a lot of clicking back and forth.

Comment: Nope. That's the shortest path.